# Sort object properties in an array based on another custom array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object array

```
item_array = [{
                "Email Address": "c",
                "First Name": "a",
                "Last Name": "b",
                "Permission": "Training Administrator",
                "Telephone": "d",
                "User Group": "Company Administrator"
            },
            {
                "Email Address": "3",
                "First Name": "1",
                "Last Name": "2",
                "Permission": "6",
                "Telephone": "4",
                "User Group": "5"
            }];
```

How can i sort this array by given array like this

```
item_order = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email Address", "Permission", "Telephone", "User Group"];
```

I need to sort object array of object like given array

> iteam_order

Expected result

```
item_array = [{
                "First Name": "a",
                "Last Name": "b",
                "Email Address": "c",
                "Permission": "Training Administrator",
                "Telephone": "d",
                "User Group": "Company Administrator"
            },
            {
                "First Name": "1",
                "Last Name": "2",
                "Email Address": "3",
                "Permission": "6",
                "Telephone": "4",
                "User Group": "5"
            }];
```

Comment: No i need to sort this object array by given custom array not an alphabetic order

Comment: In JavaScript, sorting is for arrays, not for objects. See the linked post for detailed answer and possible alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```js
const item_array = [{"Email Address":"c","First Name":"a","Last Name":"b","Permission":"Training Administrator","Telephone":"d","User Group":"Company Administrator"},{"Email Address":"3","First Name":"1","Last Name":"2","Permission":"6","Telephone":"4","User Group":"5"}],
      item_order = ["First Name","Last Name","Email Address","Permission","Telephone","User Group"];

const ordered = item_array.map(item =>
    item_order.reduce((acc, key) => ( acc[key] = item[key], acc ), {})
);

console.log(ordered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the reference array indices as the sorting order, implement the sort logic in the sort function and extract the keys of the object and sort them according to the given array and push the sorted object inside the original array.

```js
var item_array = [{ "Email Address": "c", "First Name": "a", "Last Name": "b", "Permission": "Training Administrator",  "Telephone": "d", "User Group": "Company Administrator" }, {"Email Address": "3", "First Name": "1", "Last Name": "2", "Permission": "6", "Telephone": "4", "User Group": "5"}];
var item_order = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email Address", "Permission", "Telephone", "User Group"];
item_array.forEach((obj, idx, arr) => {
           arr[idx] = Object.keys(obj)
                            .sort((a, b) => {
                             return item_order.indexOf(a) - item_order.indexOf(b);
                             })
                            .reduce((acc, ele)=>{acc[ele] = obj[ele]; return acc;},{});
                  });

console.log(item_array);
```