# javascript sort array of string by value after special character

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I want to sort by array which contains value having colon (:)

This is the below input

```
[
  'Severity',
  'Name',
  'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
  'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
  'U3B SCM: APTT-Pressure (Bara)',      
  'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',      
  'U1B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',      
  'U1B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',      
  'U3B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',      
  'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)',    
  'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)',    
  'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)',
  'U3B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)',
  'U1B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)',
  'U1B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)',
  'U3B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)',
  'U1B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position',
  'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position',
  'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position',
  'Alarms',
  'Advisories',
  '__row_index'
]
```

I want to sort / group it by the value after colon (:)

This should be below output

```
[
    'Severity',
    'Name': 'U3B',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',    // grouped by UPTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',    //grouped by DPTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Pressure (Bara)', // grouped by APTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)', // grouped by UPTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)', // grouped by DPTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)', // grouped by APTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U1B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position', // grouped by PCV-CHOKE status - Control position
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position',
    'Alarms',
    'Advisories',
    '__row_index',
]
```

I need to sort this array value which lies after ":" Eg: APTT-Temp (DegC)

How can i sort / group array values

Any help would by highly appreciated :)

Comment: The desired output is a syntax error?

Comment: Nothing about your expected results, looks ordered to me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox : sorry man initially it was object, i've updated the desired output as arrays now. :)

Comment: Please also note that neither the input nor the output are valid JSON.

Comment: @RyanWilson : sorry man my bad earlier was an object i 've updated the desired output

Comment: What's the order? It looks random

Comment: What happens if an item doesn't have `:`? The output has some at the bottom and some at the top

Comment: @evolutionxbox : bro input is random values output should be grouped by the value after 'colon' (:) if u check. it can be any order but should be grouped. hope u get it :)

Comment: @adiga: we need to check only if colon is present then sort it if its not simply leave it as it is.

Comment: What's the order of the properties they're grouped by?

Comment: @evolutionxbox : doesn't matter any order is fine but should be grouped by value after 'COLON' dats the only condition

Comment: Can the input have items without `:` in between items with `:`? Something like this: `['a', 'b:c', 'd', 'e:f', 'g', 'h']`? How does the grouping work in that case?

Comment: yes inputs can have items without colon too so basically we need group it like ['a', 'b:c', 'f:c', 'z:c', 'd', 'e:f', 'g:f', 'y:f', g, h] but group by val after ':'(colon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all groups and single values and return a flat array.

```js
const
    data = ['Severity', 'Name', 'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U3B SCM: APTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U3B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U3B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U1B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U1B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U3B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)', 'U1B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position', 'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position', 'U1B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U1B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)', 'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position', 'Alarms', 'Advisories', '__row_index'],
    map = data.reduce((m, s) => {
        const group = s.split(/:\s*/)[1] || m.size;
        return m.set(group, [...(m.get(group) || []), s]);
    }, new Map),
    grouped = Array.from(map.values()).flat(),
    counts = Array
        .from(map, ([k, { length }]) => [k, typeof k === 'string' && length])
        .filter(([, length]) => length);

console.log(counts);
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, what changed i might have to do in order to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369165/sort-array-of-objects-in-javascript-based-on-object-keys-substring

Comment: you could build a new object with the order of the grouped keys from above.

Comment: could you plz help me with this section, I need it urgently :)

Comment: @MitulPanchal Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230116)?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes what about object's value how we can fetch it  for(const key of grouped) {
    obj[key] = 'whatever';
  }

Comment: you could map ordered entries and get an object from it. `result = Object.fromEntries(grouped.map(k => [k, originalObject[k]]))`

Comment: @adiga Thanks for the reference mate !! :)

Comment: @NinaScholz : just a last question, any way i can get the count of grouped values in above example UPTT-Pressure (Bara) - count  is 3, DPTT-Pressure (Bara) - 3, APTT-Pressure (Bara) - 1

Comment: please see edit. btw, a full question would be better than to change the question in comments. for any other changes, please ask a new question.

Comment: @NinaScholz  Ok cool I'll do that for any new question, thanks for this help :)